# How to display Polymer dialog

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to get started with Google's Polymer Paper Elements 1.0 by displaying a simple message dialog:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="scripts/polymer/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<paper-dialog opened="true">Dialog test</paper-dialog>

</body>
</html>
```

The words "Dialog test" appear on the page, but there's no dialog. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: You need to include the stylesheets for those elements.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst: Hi! This is the _comment_ section. Comments are for requesting clarification. Answers go down there: ↓↓↓↓↓↓

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yay! passive aggression!

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst: You're welcome for the free information

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hey thanks man. It's a shame you don't have a ♦ next to your name.

Comment: It's no longer a shame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a reference to the `paper-dialog` element definition.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example</title>
        <script src="path/to/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="path/to/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <paper-dialog opened="true">Dialog test</paper-dialog>
    </body>
</html>
```

Including the proper import (`<link rel="import" href="path/to/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html" />`) will allow the element to be recognized by the browser and provide the functionality you expect including behavior and style.

For an interactive tutorial on using web components you can check out the [tutorial on component.kitchen](http://component.kitchen/tutorial).